# C++ insert element at the beginning of a vector using insert()

Tags: c++

Below I have a function which is supposed to extract from a vector into another vector the odd numbers and in the old vector i want to insert the even numbers at the beginning of the vector so that later to resize is. I know it is not really an effective way but I have a problem from a book to test the speed of the variant with resize instead of erasing, which I think would have the same speed anyway.. My problem is that in else when I want to insert the element which even, it does not work in this way.. What am I doing wrong in the insert function? Am I passing in a wrong way the iterator?

```
 std::vector<int> extract(std::vector<int>& even)
{
    std::vector<int> odd;
    std::vector<int>::size_type size = even.size();
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator a = even.begin();
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator b = even.end();

    while (a != b)
    {
        if ((*a) % 2 != 0)
        {
            odd.push_back((*a)); 
        }
        else
        {
            even.insert(even.begin(),(*a));
        }
        a++;
    }



    //even.resize(size);

    return odd;
}
```

Comment: You can't modify a vector while iterating through it. every change to the vector will invalidate all of your iterators.

Comment: Why inserting? The old vector is large enough to keep all even (or odd) numbers. If the vector is `1 2 3 4 6`, first you move `1 & 3` to odd vector, the you move `2` to position `0`, `4` to position `1`, etc. and finally you resize it.

Comment: Thank you The failure by Design, it worked..